# Publising app Android --> Package file not signed correctly

Tags: android, google-play, certificate

I have my application in google play. I updated my projecto to Gradle and I generated my apk to upload to Google Play. When I tried it I get the next error: the application you are trying to upload is signed with a different fingerprint to apk currently being uploaded. I checked the fingerprint of the certificate and is the same that is uploaded apk. I dont know where is the problem. This is my gradle configuration:

```
signingConfigs {

    release {
            storeFile new File("F:\\workspace\\android_keystore\\myKeystore.keystore")
            storePassword "pass"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "pass"
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure you are using same keystore & alias ?

Comment: yes, I generated the apk with my old project and the same keystore & alias and it works fine... :(

Comment: try doing this : install old app from playstore on a device. then install new app using `adb install` command if signatures are different you will get the error.

Comment: I try this. I cant install the new apk over the old apk. But the new apk is signed with the same certificate... @RahulTiwari

Comment: Try writing an email to support. use [?]  icon at top right corner of play developer console of your app and use contact us.